# Entity Framework doesn't update precision?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

Let's say that I had a SQL Server database with a table called `MyValues` and a column called `ValueA` defined as `decimal(7,4)` and I created an Entity Framework 4 model from that table within Visual Studio 2010.  The result would be an entity called `MyValue` with a `Decimal` `ValueA` property having a `Precision` set to `7`.

If I go into the database and change the datatype to become `decimal(10, 4)`, then instruct Visual Studio to "Update Module From Database..." the property remains unchanged -- the `Precision` remains `7`.

*Is this to be expected or am I missing something?*

I couldn't find any documentation on this, and was quite surprised the change wasn't made for me.  At the very least, I was expecting a validation notification that the store's precision is different than the associated entity's property's `Precision`.  It seems pretty presumptive of Entity Framework to think that the user updating the model is cognizant of minor schema changes like this, which makes me think I'm missing something.  Or is this just the nature of the beast?  If so, can anyone explain why it is the way that it is and/or *link to documentation* about topics like this.

Comment: (personal note) In my case I was made aware of all of the precision/scale changes (the sole reason I'm actually updating the model from the database), but I'm really not looking forward to making all 30+ of these property changes by hand.  Human error is something I hate to introduce into an otherwise automated tool.

Comment: Have you found out anything else about this issue? I, too, have run into a similar problem and wonder how best we can update our schema. I'll post an answer if I can find one.

Comment: @Seth0 nope, I have not. :( Entity Framework has been full of little (hidden) gems like these.